# Jeff at the library

Tags: proper-nouns, postmodification

a. Jeff, at the library, says he is going to resign.

b. Jeff at the library says he is going to resign.

Which should be used if there are two Jeffs and one is trying to clarify which Jeff one is talking about?

Jeff, the one who works at the library,....

Comment: The second one is correct

Comment: Could one use: "The Jeff at the library...?" Meaning: not the other one?

Comment: Yes, that works too. But most people would probably only use that if they had been talking about the other Jeff previously. Or if the other Jeff was closer/talked about significantly more often

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is b.

"Jeff at the library" is a whole phrase referring to a person. Since "at the library" is necessary to clarify which "Jeff" you're talking about, it can't be removed, meaning it's not optional, and therefore can't be put in between the commas.